# Ruby: Extended instance variables

Tags: ruby

How can I set some instance variables when `extend`ing a instance in the same way it can be done when creating it, with `initialize`.

In this example the variable set when extending is "lost":

```
module Mod
  def self.extended(base)
    @from_module = "Hello from Mod"
    puts "Setting variable to: #{@from_module}"
  end

  def hello_from_module
    return @from_module
  end
end

class Klass
  def initialize
    @from_class = "Hello from Klass"
  end

  def hello_from_class
    return @from_class
  end
end

klass = Klass.new       #=> #<Klass:0x00000000ed8618 @from_class="Hello from Klass">
klass.extend(Mod)       #=> #<Klass:0x00000000ed8618 @from_class="Hello from Klass">
"Setting variable to: Hello from Mod"

klass.hello_from_class  #=> "Hello from Klass"
klass.hello_from_module #=> nil (warning: instance variable @from_module not initialized)
```

Comment: The variable isn't lost. Instance variables belong to objects (instances), that's why they are called instance variables. What is the instance that your are setting the variable on? Well, the method is a singleton method of `Mod`, so `self` is `Mod` and the instance variable is an instance variable of `Mod`.

Comment: It's worth noting that `return` is implicit in Ruby, the last thing left on the stack is the return value by default, so it can usually be omitted if the last thing in the method is what you want as a return value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do what you describe.

The most common one would be to use [`instance_variable_get`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_get) and [`instance_variable_set`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-instance_variable_set):

```
module ModA
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_variable_set(:@from_module, "Hello from Mod A")
    puts "Setting variable to: #{base.instance_variable_get(:@from_module)}"
  end

  def hello_from_module
    return @from_module
  end
end
```

Another common technique is to use any of the `eval` or `exec` methods. In this case [`instance_exec`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/BasicObject.html#method-i-instance_exec):

```
module ModB
  def self.extended(base)
    base.instance_exec { @from_module = "Hello from Mod B" }
    puts "Setting variable to: #{base.instance_exec { @from_module }}"
  end

  def hello_from_module
    return @from_module
  end
end
```